# Use "contains" and "iexact" at the same query in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I use `contains` and `iexact` Field lookups at the same query in Django?

Like that ..

```
casas = Casa.objects.filter(nome_fantasia__contains__iexact='green')
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you need case-insensitive `contains`, use [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains):

```
casas = Casa.objects.filter(nome_fantasia__icontains = 'green')
```

Which is converted to

```
... WHERE nome_fantasia ILIKE '%green%'
```

in SQL.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, you don't need to. The two resultsets overlap. If you were intending `AND` then just use the most restrictive: `__iexact`. if you want `OR` use `__contains`

Just to answer your question you could do something like below (note this is an `AND`)

```
casas = Casa.objects.filter(nome_fantasia__contains='green', nome_fantasia__iexact='green')
```

Comment: His question is almost certainly how to do a case-insensitive `contains`.

Comment: My answer answers the question as it was phrased. You may be right though. We'll see, what he says when he jumps back on.

Comment: See his comment on my answer.

Comment: they need a badge for decoding poorly phrased questions, which you sir would have just earned.